# Parsing commands from user input

Tags: parsing, user-input

This question is intended to be a discussion of people's personal opinions in handling user input.

This portion of the project that I am working on handles user input in a manner similar to an IRC chat.  For instance, there are set commands and whatnot, for chatting, executing actions, etc.

Now, I have several options to choose from for parsing this input.  I could go with regular expressions, I could parse it directly (ie a large switch statement with all supported commands, simply checking the first x number of characters in the user input), or could even go crazy and add in a parser similar to Flex/Bison implementations.  One other option I was considering was defining all commands in an XML file to separate them from the code implementation.

So, what are the thoughts of the community?

Comment: This site is designed to encourage good, objective answers.  I suspect that phrasing your question to be an explicit discussion about personal opinions will turn out poorly.  I'd suggest rephrasing it to, "Best user input practices - php" or something more concrete and objectively measurable.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated it accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with a nice mixed bag of all.

Obviously you'll have to sanitize the input. Make sure there's no nasty stuff there, depending on where the input is going to prevent SQL injection, XSS, CSRF etc...

But when your input is clean, you could go with a regexp that catches the ones intended as command and gets all necessary submatches (command parameters etc.) and then have some sort of dispatcher-switch statement or similar.

There really is no cover-all best practice here, apart from always always and quadruple-always making sure user input is sanitized. Apart from that, go with what seems to fit best for your case.

Obviously there are those that say if you've got a problem and you're thinking of using reg exps to solve said problem, you've got two problems, but used cautiously, they're the best thing ever. Just remember that regexp-monsters can read to really poor readability really quick.